# How to custom parse dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I know this seems like a duplicated question (and it kinda is), but previous answers didn't let me achieve what I'm looking for. I have a date Series with the following format:

```
     date
 Jun 13 14:46
 Jun 13 17:11
```

And so, I wanted to turn it into a `datetime` object. I did the following:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%b %d %I:%M')
```

Which based on this question should be enough: [Convert custom date formats in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396263/convert-custom-date-formats-in-pandas])

But, I'm still getting `ValueError: time data 'Jun 13 14:46' does not match format '%b %d %I:%M' (match)`

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%b %d %H:%M')`

`%I` is for a 12-hour clock.

`%H` is for a 24-hour clock.

Comment: Damn. Thanks, that solves the issue! Do you know where can I find the meaning of all the date FormatString? I wasn't able to find them

Comment: in the docs for the `datetime.strptime` function:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior